# Hash linking and jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I wanted to ask about strange behaviour.

I have got form and inside this form I have:

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="{$smarty.server.SCRIPT_URI}#comments">
```

This form creates new post and code above redirect to desired page and `#comments DIV`.

Normally, when query mobile is disabled in code, this works as I want. After form submission post is created and script redirect to div with this ID.

But when I enable jquery mobile script, page redirect after submission, but not scroll to comment DIV. Just redirect and show page as normal.

Here is my jquery mobile code:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
  $.extend(  $.mobile , {
    ajaxEnabled: false,
    hashListeningEnabled:false,
    linkBindingEnabled:false,
    pushStateEnabled:false
  });
});
```

Thank You for any advice.